# Longest path in a graph.

Tags: graph-theory

How do I prove that the longest path in a graph that starts from the vertex $\ v_1 $, includes all the adjacent vertices of $\ v_1 $?

Comment: For a counter example consider star graphs and let $v_1$ be its center.

Comment: @Shahab Star is not counter example since the longest path does not start from the center $v_1$ (the longest path in star is of length 3).

Comment: I don't mean an example, I need a proof.

Comment: @M.Badaoui I thought the OP meant that the longest path that starts from $v_1$. Otherwise the longest path will include all adjacent vertices of the terminal vertex for otherwise it will be extendable.

Comment: @Shahab Could you please explain how can we extend it? (since the vertices of  the neighbor of $v_1$ could be not connected).

Comment: @M.Badaoui If $w$ is adjacent to $v_1$ and $w$ is not on the path $P$ starting from $v_1$ consider the path $wP$. It is longer than $P$.

Comment: @Shahab But it is no longer a path that starts from the vertex $v_1$. OP explicitly states "longest path that starts from the vertex $v_1$".

Comment: @5xum In which case the star graph example shows the OP's statement is false.

Comment: @Shahab Yes  this is the answer, if it is not, then longest path will start from $w$ instead of $v_1$ which will be contradiction

Comment: I see, if we take into accout the path that includes v1 it will include also all the adjacents of v1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You claim:

> For every vertex $v_1$, the longest path that starts in $v_1$ includes all adjacent vertices of $v_1$

This is false. If you have a graph with four vertices, $a,b,cd$, and three edges, $(a,b)$, $(b,c)$, $(c,d)$ then the longest path that starts at $b$ is the path $b\to c\to d$ and it does not include $a$.

Comment: "the longest path in a graph that starts from the vertex $v_1$" may have double meaning: 1-The longest path in the graph where $v_1$ is its source. 2- The longest path from any vertex $v_1$ (your answer or the star are counter example).

Answer (score -1):

Let $P$ be a longest path in the graph that stars at vertex $v_1$. We will prove that $P$ contains all neighbours of $v_1$. Suppose not. Then, there is a vertex $v_2$ adjacent to $v_1$ such that $P$ does not contain $v_2$. But that implies that we can join path $P$ with path $v_1v_2$, obtaining a path longer than $P$, a contradiction to the fact that $P$ is a longest path.

Comment: However, the new path you formed is not a path which starts at $v_1$.

Comment: I am considering any longest path of the graph. Not just those starting at $v_1$.

Comment: The statement of the question is wrong. The solution I gave is for the correct versión of the question

Comment: I think this answer can be improved if you word the question you interpreted in your answer as well, like "Given a longest path in a graph, show that for its starting vertex $v$, all the neighbours of $v$ are included in the path."